# how to style two images differently in html5 using css3

Tags: html, css

i want to style to images differently in html5 using css3 but putting in mind the semantics feature of html5. How can i style two images differently which are situated in the same section and  same article.

the only thing i found was you can do is using div in css3 or by styling within html document for every image(which is not recommended in html 5).

Comment: Can you please include your code that demonstrates your current structure and desired styling? Also, consider looking into the [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child), which can be helpful if you have a static number of elements and want to style certain ones differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the images ids:

```
<img src='<Image URL>' id='image1'></img>
```

css:

```
# image1{
<< CSS PROPERTIES HERE >>>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `img:nth-child()` in your css

More details: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp